# ReadLine - Array index out of bounds

Tags: c#-4.0

I have been debugging this program to find the error but couldn't succeed in that. For some reason, it is displaying an error - array index out of bounds in this line 
 moves[nCount].sDirection = sStep[0]; I know, this forum is not meant for debugging, im sorry for that.

```
      class Program
{
     struct move
    {
       public char sDirection;
       public int steps;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int nNumOfInstructions = 0;
        int nStartX = 0, nStartY = 0;
        move[] moves = new move[nNumOfInstructions];


        nNumOfInstructions=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        string sPosCoOrd = Console.ReadLine();
        nStartX = Convert.ToInt32(sPosCoOrd[0]);

        nStartY = Convert.ToInt32(sPosCoOrd[2]);

        string sStep = "";

        for (int nCount = 0; nCount < nNumOfInstructions; nCount++)
        {
            sStep = Console.ReadLine();
            int length = sStep.Length;
            moves[nCount].sDirection = sStep[0];
            moves[nCount].steps = Convert.ToInt32(sStep[1]);


        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `moves` array is created as an array of zero length. For any index, accessing this array will inevitably throw an Array index out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do it this way:

```
class Program
{
    struct move
    {
        public char sDirection;
        public int steps;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int nNumOfInstructions = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        move[] moves = new move[nNumOfInstructions];

        string sPosCoOrd = Console.ReadLine();
        int nStartX = Convert.ToInt32(sPosCoOrd[0]);
        int nStartY = Convert.ToInt32(sPosCoOrd[2]);

        string sStep = String.Empty;

        for (int nCount = 0; nCount < nNumOfInstructions; nCount++)
        {
            sStep = Console.ReadLine();
            int length = sStep.Length;
            moves[nCount].sDirection = sStep[0];
            moves[nCount].steps = Convert.ToInt32(sStep[1]);
        }
    }
}
```